# How to find the first True value in a data frame column based on index value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Getting error when I run the following code.

```
s1 = pd.Series(dfs.index)
s2 = []
for x in df.index:   
    for i in s1:
       if x > i & df['test'].loc[x] == True:
           s2.append(df['shiftdt'])
```

dfs = are the year and qt of the start of a recession

```
16     1949q1
34     1953q3
51     1957q4
255    2008q4
Name: shiftdt, dtype: object
```

df looks like this:

```
    Unnamed: 4 GDP      shift1    shift2 shiftdt   test  
14      1948q4      280.7    279.5    272.9  1948q3   True  
15      1949q1      275.4    280.7    279.5  1948q4  False
16      1949q2      271.7    275.4    280.7  1949q1  False
17      1949q3      273.3    271.7    275.4  1949q2  False
18      1949q4        271    273.3    271.7  1949q3  False 
19      1950q1      281.2      271    273.3  1949q4  False
20      1950q2      290.7    281.2      271  1950q1   True
21      1950q3      308.5    290.7    281.2  1950q2   True
```

df is a list of yearqt like the ones in dfs but also includes the GDP, a shifted column of the GDP, another shifted column of the first shifted column and a boolean value that is True if gdp > shift1 and shift1>shift2.  i'm trying to identify the end of the recession but my problem is that there are plenty of times where two consecutive quarters are better than the prior one.  my goal is to use the index value of dfs (which is in line with df) and get the first True after each index value.  (sorry so complicated to explain)

Comment: Sample of acutal dataframe would be really helpful. Since you are saying `gdp > shift1` we need to see `gdp` and `shift 1` and `shift2` .

Comment: Looks something like this :Unnamed: 4 GDP     shift1     shift2         shiftdt   test  test2 /n
9       1947q3      250.1    246.3    243.1  1947q2   True    NaN/n
10      1947q4      260.3    250.1    246.3  1947q3   True   True/n
11      1948q1      266.2    260.3    250.1  1947q4   True   True/n

Comment: Add the same in the question and what you want the output to be for this sample data

Comment: Please put any  additional information into the question, as formatting in comments is extremely limited.

Comment: What would be very helpful is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What this would mean is the inclusion of a sample version of `df` and `dfs` so we can work with it in our interpreters.

Comment: ok i added a sample of the df data frame.  my goal is to get that first true after all the false.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
```

Create column with index where values are True:

```
df['new_index'] = np.where(df.test == True, df.index, np.nan)
```

Backfill:

```
df.new_index = df.new_index.new_index.bfill()
```